# How to use Real-World-Weight Cross-Entropy loss in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I'm working on multiclass classification where some mistakes are more severe than others. Therefore, I would like to incorporate the costs into my loss function. I found this under the name Real-World-Weight Cross-Entropy, described [in this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8943952). The formula goes as below:

[image]

I haven't find any ready-to-use implementation, apart from `weight` argument of standard `CrossEntropyLoss`, which I believe works quite different to my use-case (as far as I understand the cost of incorrectly classifying one category is the same no matter with which category it was confused).

How can I apply this in PyTorch?

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)

cost_matrix = torch.zeros((5, 5))
cost_matrix[1, 0] = 0.4
cost_matrix[2, 0] = 0.1
cost_matrix[2, 1] = 0.9
cost_matrix[3, 0] = 0.4
cost_matrix[3, 1] = 0.9
cost_matrix[3, 2] = 0.1
cost_matrix[4, 0] = 0.1
cost_matrix[4, 1] = 0.4
cost_matrix[4, 2] = 0.9
cost_matrix[4, 3] = 0.1
cost_matrix[0, 1] = 0.4
cost_matrix[0, 2] = 0.1
cost_matrix[1, 2] = 0.9
cost_matrix[0, 3] = 0.4
cost_matrix[1, 3] = 0.9
cost_matrix[2, 3] = 0.1
cost_matrix[0, 4] = 0.1
cost_matrix[1, 4] = 0.4
cost_matrix[2, 4] = 0.9
cost_matrix[3, 4] = 0.1
```

Comment: I did not understand your cost_matrix ? what did you mean by the values assigned to cost_matrix ? From where should you calculate these values?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you investigating this notebook, it contains the full implementation by the author of the paper indicated in your question:
[The-Real-World-Weight-Crossentropy-Loss-Function](https://github.com/yaoshiang/The-Real-World-Weight-Crossentropy-Loss-Function/blob/master/Real_World_Weighted_Crossentropy_Loss_Function.ipynb).